# Extent of a group of lines in a polyline shapefile

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, atlas

QGIS, shapefiles

I have a map with a polyline layer representing streets of a village
I have a shapefile without geometry, with the lists of responsible peoples for streets, each of them is reponsible for several streets. The street shapefile has a field referencing its responsible id.

I want to produce a report by responsible, with the list of streets he is responsible for, and a map showing his streets.

I create an atlas report, based on the reponsible table, create a text field with an aggregate formula to list his streets. No problem with this

```
'Streets : ' || aggregate (layer:= "Streets",  aggregate:='concatenate', expression:= "Nom", filter:= RespCtrl = attribute(@parent, 'RespId'), concatenator:= ', ')
```

I want also to show a map that shows all the streets he is responsible for!
Atlas control is not available (as initial shapefile has no geometry), so I have to use the extend minx, miny, maxx, maxy, but do not know how to extract the extremities of all the streets for this responsible.
I tested something like :

```
 aggregate(layer:=  "streets"  ,
    aggregate:= max,
    expression:= x_max(???geometry???),                   
filter:= "RespCtrl" =  attribute( @parent, "RespId") )
```

Is this the right approach, and if it is, what to put in `x_max()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much easier: Create a copy of the street layer: Use [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) and for `Group by expression` use the field with the responsible id. Make sure that the aggregate function for this `responsible_id` field ist set to `first_value`.

[image]

You get a new line layer with one multipart line feature that contains all streets of a responsible. Use this layer as atlas coverage layer. To get the name of the person responsible for the streets in the current atlas feature, use this expression:

```
attribute (
    get_feature ('persons','id',responsible_id),
    'name'
)
```

*Click to enlarge: project (left), atlas (right), showing the streets with id=3 (blue), corresponding to Johnson:*
[image]

If you want that only the street of the current responsible is visible in the atlas, not the other streets, set the opacity of the layer to data driven override with this expression: `if ($id=  @atlas_featureid, 100,0)`. Change `0` to e.g. `50` to make the other streets semi-transparent and use the same principle to make current atlas features larger, other streets thinner like in the following example:

*Atlas sheet for persion with id 4 = Tinner (yellow street lines); all other streets are drawn thinner and semi-transparent:*
[image]

Comment: Sounds great ! Thank you. I will work on it. Just one question, Is the new layer dynamicaly linked to the layer street or shuld I recreate it in case of modification (geometry, responsible,...)?

Comment: It is not dynamic, you have to recreate it after changes. Only virtual layers are dynamic

Comment: I have tested and it  works exactly as expected. Thanks