# Use of automatically generated Python procedure

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console

I asked a question some days ago (see [Extent of a group of lines in a polyline shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473977/extent-of-a-group-of-lines-in-a-polyline-shapefile)) and got a nice answer that works: use aggregate procedure in the processing toolbox.
Unfortunately, this process generates a 'temporary layer", that is lost when you close the application. So, I tried to make this process reproducible.
I saw that, when preparing the request in the aggregate screen, you can, in the advanced button, "Copy as Python command", and then I could save it. I want to replay this procedure, but when I run it in the Python console, it seems to run but generate nothing.

What can I do with this procedure, where can I run it again?

The procedure generated is as follows:

`processing.run("native:aggregate", {'INPUT':'D:/Data_CV/CapDemain5140/Sentiers5140/Projets/2022 PointsNoeudsPietonsProvince/CartographiePNP/JonctionsPN.shp','GROUP_BY':'NULL','AGGREGATES':[{'aggregate': 'first_value','delimiter': ',','input': '"RespCtrl"','length': 5,'name': 'RespCtrl','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"Nom"','length': -1,'name': 'Nom','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'sum','delimiter': ',','input': '"Longueur"','length': -1,'name': 'Longueur','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 6,'type_name': 'double precision'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"PNExtremit"','length': -1,'name': 'PNExtremit','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'sum','delimiter': ',','input': '"NbPick"','length': 10,'name': 'NbPick','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 2,'type_name': 'integer'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"PickNumber"','length': -1,'name': 'PickNumber','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'}],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple script like this you can also save it in the script editor alongside the Python console:

[image: python script editor]

This makes it much easier to edit and reuse. Then, as already mentioned, you can direct the output to a file (line 12 in my example)

For a more serious approach you can try making a graphical processing model, which can also preserve an aggregate configuration. With a processing model, you can specify the output destination easily and graphically with each run.

[image: aggregate processing model]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I create and run it in the preparation screen of "aggregate" function from the Processing toolbox, I have a layer appearing in the layer list. If I close and reopen QGis, this layer desapears as it is an "in memory" layer. So in the Python console, I run the script, and I was expecting the "in memory" layer to be recreated, but nothing appeared and no error highlighted in the console.

Comment: In the Aggregate preparation screen of the Processing toolbox, you can also set the output destination to a file (the last parameter). Have you tried that?
And in the Python console, if you specify a .shp as output, the Shapefile will be created but not loaded (and no errors will be raised). To also load the created layer, replace `processing.run()` with `processing.runAndLoadResults()`

Comment: Yes it works with shp file and runandload. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is generating an output in a temporary directory. See the `'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` parameter at the end.

You have various options how to proceed including:

1. Replacing `'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` with a file path (shapefile or geopackage compliant path)
2. Assign the procedure to a variable such as

```py
result = processing.run("native:aggregate", {'INPUT':'D:/Data_CV/CapDemain5140/Sentiers5140/Projets/2022 PointsNoeudsPietonsProvince/CartographiePNP/JonctionsPN.shp','GROUP_BY':'NULL','AGGREGATES':[{'aggregate': 'first_value','delimiter': ',','input': '"RespCtrl"','length': 5,'name': 'RespCtrl','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"Nom"','length': -1,'name': 'Nom','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'sum','delimiter': ',','input': '"Longueur"','length': -1,'name': 'Longueur','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 6,'type_name': 'double precision'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"PNExtremit"','length': -1,'name': 'PNExtremit','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'},{'aggregate': 'sum','delimiter': ',','input': '"NbPick"','length': 10,'name': 'NbPick','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 2,'type_name': 'integer'},{'aggregate': 'concatenate','delimiter': ',','input': '"PickNumber"','length': -1,'name': 'PickNumber','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'}],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

This will return a dictionary. To capture the processed `QgsVectorLayer` you can use

```py
result['OUTPUT']
```